# How to use average function in neo4j with collection

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to calculate covariance of two vectors as collection
A=[1, 2, 3, 4] 
B=[5, 6, 7, 8]

Cov(A,B)= Sigma[(ai-AVGa)*(bi-AVGb)] / (n-1)

My problem for covariance computation is:

1) I can not have a nested aggregate function 
when I write

```
SUM((ai-avg(a)) * (bi-avg(b)))
```

2) Or in another shape, how can I extract two collection with one reduce such as:

```
REDUCE(x= 0.0, ai IN COLLECT(a) | bi IN COLLECT(b) | x + (ai-avg(a))*(bi-avg(b)))
```

3) if it is not possible to extract two collection in oe reduce how it is possible to relate their value to calculate covariance when they are separated

```
REDUCE(x= 0.0, ai IN COLLECT(a) | x + (ai-avg(a)))
REDUCE(y= 0.0, bi IN COLLECT(b) | y + (bi-avg(b)))
```

I mean that can I write nested reduce?

4) Is there any ways with "unwind", "extract"

Thank you in advanced for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

cybersam's answer is totally fine but if you want to avoid the `n^2` Cartesian product that results from the double UNWIND you can do this instead:

```
WITH [1,2,3,4] AS a, [5,6,7,8] AS b
WITH REDUCE(s = 0.0, x IN a | s + x) / SIZE(a) AS e_a,
     REDUCE(s = 0.0, x IN b | s + x) / SIZE(b) AS e_b,
     SIZE(a) AS n, a, b
RETURN REDUCE(s = 0.0, i IN RANGE(0, n - 1) | s + ((a[i] - e_a) * (b[i] - e_b))) / (n - 1) AS cov;
```

Edit:

Not calling anyone out, but let me elaborate more on why you would want to avoid the double UNWIND in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34423783/2848578. Like I said below, UNWINDing k length-n collections in Cypher results in `n^k` rows. So let's take two length-3 collections over which you want to calculate the covariance.

```
> WITH [1,2,3] AS a, [4,5,6] AS b
UNWIND a AS aa
UNWIND b AS bb
RETURN aa, bb;
   | aa | bb
---+----+----
 1 |  1 |  4
 2 |  1 |  5
 3 |  1 |  6
 4 |  2 |  4
 5 |  2 |  5
 6 |  2 |  6
 7 |  3 |  4
 8 |  3 |  5
 9 |  3 |  6
```

Now we have `n^k = 3^2 = 9` rows. At this point, taking the average of these identifiers means we're taking the average of 9 values.

```
> WITH [1,2,3] AS a, [4,5,6] AS b
UNWIND a AS aa
UNWIND b AS bb
RETURN AVG(aa), AVG(bb);
   | AVG(aa) | AVG(bb)
---+---------+---------
 1 |     2.0 |     5.0
```

Also as I said below, this doesn't affect the answer because the average of a repeating vector of numbers will always be the same. For example, the average of {1,2,3} is equal to the average of {1,2,3,1,2,3}. It is likely inconsequential for small values of `n`, but when you start getting larger values of `n` you'll start seeing a performance decrease.

Let's say you have two length-1000 vectors. Calculating the average of each with a double UNWIND:

```
> WITH RANGE(0, 1000) AS a, RANGE(1000, 2000) AS b
UNWIND a AS aa
UNWIND b AS bb
RETURN AVG(aa), AVG(bb);
   | AVG(aa) | AVG(bb)
---+---------+---------
 1 |   500.0 |  1500.0
```

**714 ms**

Is significantly slower than using REDUCE:

```
> WITH RANGE(0, 1000) AS a, RANGE(1000, 2000) AS b
RETURN REDUCE(s = 0.0, x IN a | s + x) / SIZE(a) AS e_a,
       REDUCE(s = 0.0, x IN b | s + x) / SIZE(b) AS e_b;
   | e_a   | e_b   
---+-------+--------
 1 | 500.0 | 1500.0
```

**4 ms**

To bring it all together, I'll compare the two queries in full on length-1000 vectors:

```
> WITH RANGE(0, 1000) AS aa, RANGE(1000, 2000) AS bb
UNWIND aa AS a
UNWIND bb AS b
WITH aa, bb, SIZE(aa) AS n, AVG(a) AS avgA, AVG(b) AS avgB
RETURN REDUCE(s = 0, i IN RANGE(0,n-1)| s +((aa[i]-avgA)*(bb[i]-avgB)))/(n-1) AS
 covariance;
   | covariance
---+------------
 1 |    83583.5
```

**9105 ms**

```
> WITH RANGE(0, 1000) AS a, RANGE(1000, 2000) AS b
WITH REDUCE(s = 0.0, x IN a | s + x) / SIZE(a) AS e_a,
     REDUCE(s = 0.0, x IN b | s + x) / SIZE(b) AS e_b,
          SIZE(a) AS n, a, b
          RETURN REDUCE(s = 0.0, i IN RANGE(0, n - 1) | s + ((a[i] - e_a) * (b[i
] - e_b))) / (n - 1) AS cov;
   | cov    
---+---------
 1 | 83583.5
```

**33 ms**

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you explain more about why we should avoid the n^2 Cartesian?

Comment: When you UNWIND k length-n collections, you end up with `n^k` rows. So if your k=2 vectors (or Cypher collections) have 1000 values, the double UNWIND brings you to `1000^2 = 1,000,000 rows` over which you're calculating those averages in the subsequent WITH clause. It doesn't affect the answer, because avg(1,2,3,4) = avg(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4) but you're doing more computation than you need.

Comment: Thank so much @Nicole White for your description, I got it completely, so it has huge influence when we are working on huge or big data !

Comment: Yeah, @MahsaHassankashi, see my edits. You'll see serious performance issues with large vectors if you use UNWIND.

Comment: thank you so much for your complete explanation, but I wanna know just for myself that if there are some situations such as opening json collection which has parent and child (without any computation for aggregate functions and just for adding or node modification  ) -> therefore using unwind is useful ?! because I heard that it helps to have a better performance.

Comment: I'm not saying to never use UNWIND. I'm saying in this particular case that the double UNWIND will lead to issues with large vectors. @jjaderberg answered after me I think but his answer is also good because it avoids the `n^2` expansion as well. All of these answers are fine for small `n` but you'll start to see differences as `n` grows, again for the reasons I described above.

Answer (score 6):

[EDITED]

This should calculate the covariance (according to your formula), given your sample inputs:

```
WITH [1,2,3,4] AS aa, [5,6,7,8] AS bb
UNWIND aa AS a
UNWIND bb AS b
WITH aa, bb, SIZE(aa) AS n, AVG(a) AS avgA, AVG(b) AS avgB
RETURN REDUCE(s = 0, i IN RANGE(0,n-1)| s +((aa[i]-avgA)*(bb[i]-avgB)))/(n-1) AS covariance;
```

This approach is OK when `n` is small, as is the case with the original sample data.

However, as @NicoleWhite and @jjaderberg point out, when `n` is not small, this approach will be inefficient. The answer by @NicoleWhite is an elegant general solution.

Comment: Nice, you beat me to it :) but I think your unwind will create a cross product

Comment: @jjaderberg Could you explain more about "cross product" when we have nested UNWIND?

Comment: @MahsaHassankashi Unwinding two collections of four items results in sixteen combinations. For every item in either collection each item in the other collection is represented. This is a cross product (sometimes called a Cartesian product) and often happens in an ill considered `MATCH`, such as `MATCH (a:Person), (b:Person)` giving the square of the number of nodes with label `:Person`. It does not matter for the results in this case, because the average of four collections of `[5, 6, 7, 8]` is the same as the average of `[5, 6, 7, 8]`.

Comment: @jjaderberg thanks a lot , so as I understand , in these cases , nested unwind does not matter for final result but had impact on performance?

Comment: Yes, but only accidentally. It works because you are calculating an average. If you were to do two unwinds and then `sum()` you would get incorrect results.

Answer (score 4):

How do you arrive at collections `A` and `B`? The `avg` function is an *aggregating function* and cannot be used in the `REDUCE` context, nor can it be applied to collections. You should calculate your average before you get to that point, but exactly how to do that best depends on how you arrive at the two collections of values. If you are at a point where you have individual result items that you then `collect` to get `A` and `B`, that's the point when you could use `avg`. For example:

```
WITH [1, 2, 3, 4] AS aa UNWIND aa AS a
WITH collect(a) AS aa, avg(a) AS aAvg
RETURN aa, aAvg
```

and for both collections

```
WITH [1, 2, 3, 4] AS aColl UNWIND aColl AS a
WITH collect(a) AS aColl, avg(a) AS aAvg
WITH aColl, aAvg,[5, 6, 7, 8] AS bColl UNWIND bColl AS b
WITH aColl, aAvg, collect(b) AS bColl, avg(b) AS bAvg
RETURN aColl, aAvg, bColl, bAvg
```

Once you have the two averages, let's call them `aAvg` and `bAvg`, and the two collections, `aColl` and `bColl`, you can do

```
RETURN REDUCE(x = 0.0, i IN range(0, size(aColl) - 1) | x + ((aColl[i] - aAvg) * (bColl[i] - bAvg))) / (size(aColl) - 1) AS covariance
```

Comment: I get collection from a query: MATCH (me)-[:HAS]->(myFavorites)-[x:TAGGED]->(tag)
         <-[y:TAGGED]-(theirFavorites)<-[:HAS]-(people)
WHERE me.name = 'Mahsa' AND people.name='Frank'  actually I wanna read the property type on edge of "TAGGED" and vectores a and b will be produced on this point.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much Dears, however I wonder which one is most efficient

1) Nested unwind and range inside reduce -> @cybersam

2) nested Reduce -> @Nicole White

3) Nested With (reset query by with) -> @jjaderberg

BUT Important Issue is :

Why there is an error and difference between your computations and real and actual computations.

I mean your covariance equals to = **1.6666666666666667**

But in real world covariance equals to = **1.25**

please check: https://www.easycalculation.com/statistics/covariance.php

Vector X: [1, 2, 3, 4]
Vector Y: [5, 6, 7, 8]

[image]

[image]

I think this differences is because that some computation do not consider (n-1) as divisor and instead of (n-1) , just they use n. Therefore when we grow divisor from n-1 to n the result will be diminished from 1.6 to 1.25.

[image]

Comment: You gave the formula as `Cov(A,B)= Sigma[(ai-AVGa)*(bi-AVGb)] / (n-1)` and I didn't pause to consider it. With the means `2.5` and `6.5` (which is what all of our answers give) the result is `1.666etc` when the final divisor is `n-1`, but `1.25` when the final divisor is `n`.

Comment: The covariance is 1.67. You can confirm this in R: `cov(c(1,2,3,4), c(5,6,7,8)) [1] 1.666667`. I wouldn't rely on some online calculator like that.

Comment: @jjaderberg yes exactly , I remember that there is difference because of divisor  from n-1 to n

Comment: We use `n - 1` because we are calculating the sample covariance. You use `n - k` when calculating sample statistics where `k` is the number of intermediate statistics you need to calculate to arrive at your final statistic. In this case, you need to calculate `k = 1` (the sample mean) statistics before arriving at your final answer. Thus your degrees of freedom is `n - 1` and that is your denominator. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(statistics)